# How to prevent pandas.Dataframe.hist() from creating subplots with superimposed data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to display two dataframe columns with respect to a third one. Here is what my code looks like:

```
  1 import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                            
  2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                               
  3                                                                                                               
  4 col1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]                                                                        
  5 col2=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]                                                                        
  6 col3=[1,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75]                                                          
  7                                                                                                               
  8 myDF = pd.DataFrame({'col1': col1, 'col2': col2, 'col3':col3})                                                
  9                                                                                                               
 10 myDF.hist(['col3','col3'], weights=[myDF.col1,myDF.col2])                                                     
 11                                                                                                               
 12 plt.savefig('myDF.png', format='png')
```

And here's the output:

[image: duplicated superimposed histograms]

I tried imposing a single subplot with

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (1,1))
myDF.hist(['col3','col3'], weights=[myDF.col1,myDF.col2], ax=ax)
```

But it's being overriden at runtime.
Any ideas how i can get a single plot?

**EDIT:** The following worked

```
x = [list(myDF.col3), list(myDF.col3)]
plt.hist(x, weights=[myDF.col1,myDF.col2])
```

Seems to be an issue with the pandas hist() function (?)

Answer (score 1):

I am not able in a clean way. You can try something like:

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                            
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                               

col1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]                                                                        
col2=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]                                                                        
col3=[1,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75]                                                          

myDF = pd.DataFrame({'col1': col1, 'col2': col2, 'col3':col3})                                                

ax = myDF.hist(column='col3', weights=[myDF.col1], align='mid', rwidth=0.8)
myDF.hist(column='col3', weights=[myDF.col2], ax=ax, align='mid', rwidth=0.8, alpha=0.8)
```

you can try playing around with the bars alignment (left, mid or right) and with the bars `rwidth`...

[image]

Comment: My actual data has 600+ rows and is continuous. S

Comment: so basically you want just one of the two identical plot you showed? is it correct?

Comment: Looks good, I ended up falling back on plt.hist() and it solved it as well (see edit). Not sure where the issue arises in pandas.DataFrame.hist()

Comment: I agree, it seems a very strange pandas behavior